# subject.Dispose() vs subject.OnCompleted()

Tags: c#, system.reactive, rx.net

What's the difference between `.Dispose()` and `.OnCompleted()` call on a `Subject` ?

Usually i dispose subscription to stop listening an observable and complete a subject when it's no longer useful anywhere on the code,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh229225(v=vs.103)) of the `Subject<T>.Dispose` method:

> Releases all resources used by the current instance of the `Subject<T>` class and unsubscribe all observers.

It seems that attempting to do anything with a `Subject` after disposing it, results to an `ObjectDisposedException`. You can't `Subscribe` to a disposed `Subject` for example. Any subscriptions that are active at the time the `Subject` is disposed, will be disposed too, and the unsubscribed observers will **not** receive `OnCompleted` notifications.

On the contrary a subject that has been completed by calling its `OnCompleted` method can still be subscribed at any time, in which case the subscribed observer will receive instantly an `OnCompleted` notification. Of course if the completed subject is one of the buffered types like the [`ReplaySubject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh211810(v=vs.103)), then the observers will receive a number of `OnNext` notifications before the final `OnCompleted`.

Personally I would consider calling `Dispose` to a `ReplaySubject` that is about to be discarded, in order to accelerate the recovery of the RAM used by its internal buffer. I am not sure if this would make any difference though, since the `Dispose` is generally supposed to release unmanaged resources, and the memory used by the buffer is most probably managed.

Answer (score 0):

> Usually i dispose subscription to stop listening an observable and complete a subject when it's no longer usefull[sic] anywhere on the code

I think you have those backwards. I'm not familiar with rx.net, but I do know the IDisposable and Observable patterns. IDisposable is used to release resources from an object when you are completely done with it and it's no longer useful. OnCompleted is for when you are done observing (the provider has finished sending notifications), even if the object might still have other uses.

Comment: It sounds to me like you're saying the same thing as the OP, and not backwards like you suggest.

Comment: @Enigmativity. To paraphrase the OP, I would complete a subscription to stop listening an observable and dispose a subject when it's no longer useful anywhere on the code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very important semantic difference between calling `.Dispose()` and `.OnCompleted()` on a subject.

Consider this code:

```
Subject<int> subject = new Subject<int>();

IObservable<int[]> query = subject.ToArray();

IDisposable subscription =
    query
        .Subscribe(xs => Console.WriteLine(String.Concat(xs)));

subject.OnNext(1);
subject.OnNext(2);
```

If I then call `subject.OnCompleted()` I get `12` written to the Console. If, however, I call `subject.Dispose()` then nothing gets printed.

Some operators, like `.ToArray()` in my example code, expect the `.OnCompleted()` call to produce any value.

It is important to understand what queries you are performing on the `subject` to know how to end it properly - there are situations where both ways are valid.

I feel, though, that you are doing the right things with disposing of subscriptions and completing subjects.

Comment: Would you ever consider disposing a `Subject`? If yes, in which case(s)?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - That's what I was saying when I said "there are situations where both ways are valid". If I were cancelling an operation then `.Dispose()` is the way to go. If I were wanting to close down my app and allow it to successfully deal with the values produced so far then `.OnCompleted()` would be what I do.

Comment: What would be the advantage of calling `Dispose` when canceling an operation, compared to just doing nothing and letting the `Subject` to be eventually finalized by the garbage collector?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - Calling `.Dispose()` on a `Subject<T>` appears to have only one purpose - it drops references to all subscribers. It allows the GC to clean up the subject even if the subscriber references are still rooted. Not calling `.Dispose()` could be a memory leak.

Comment: Hard to believe that the garbage collector will not be able to clean up an unreferenced `Subject` that still has undisposed subscriptions. I know from the events-model that subscribers don't keep references of publishers (only the publishers keep references of subscribers), so omitting to detach an event handler will not prevent a publisher from being garbage collected. I would expect the same to be true for the RX model of subscriptions.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - No, sorry, you're right. The subject maintains `private SubjectDisposable[] _observers;`, but that's not stopping the subject from being collected. Small brain-fart on my behalf. :-/

Comment: My guess is that the `Subject` may hold some unmanaged resource under some conditions, or did so in some early version of the RX library, and this is why the `Dispose` method was added in its API. Much like why the `Task`s are disposable, but disposing them [is not necessary](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/do-i-need-to-dispose-of-tasks/) in general. But without studying the source code I can't be sure.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - `IDisposable` is there because it is possible to to build observables that use managed resources (i.e. `Observable.Using`) and because an observable pipeline is really a nested set of calls to extension methods then any operator can contain unmanaged resources. It's also convenient to fit into the duality of enumerables and the existing language features (i.e. `using (...)`).

Comment: The `Observable.Using` operator handles the disposal of a disposable resource, but it's not disposable itself. The `IObservable`s in general are not disposable. The `Subject` is a strange exception in that respect.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - I think it was for consistency that they used `Disposable` across the library.

Comment: The only things disposable in the library, except from the `Subject`, are the subscriptions. Neither the observables nor the observers are disposable. And the `Subject` is not a subscription, it is an observable/observer dual. So itself being disposable is more a source of inconsistency IMHO.